# Imageview with Image from Url

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-image

i'm searching for a modified Imageviewclass which downloads a image and displays it.
It should also be possible to display a "download fail"-image and a "load"-image.
If anyone knows a class like this please let me know it.

Thx!

Comment: I have not seen such a component but it is a good idea.

Comment: This is a great idea, but you'll have to write it yourself. Shouldn't be too hard to sub-class the current image view and add the functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this example, just pass the Activity instance in a constructor and extend the view class instead of the Activity class.

[Web Imageview](http://asantoso.wordpress.com/2008/03/07/download-and-view-image-from-the-web/)

Comment: ok thanks, but not exactly what I#m looking for...because I want a  "download fail"-image and a "load"-image too.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps u:

```
ImageView i = new ImageView(this);
i.setImageResource(" ur load image" ) // show any load image here..eg. gallery image
try {
/* Open a new URL and get the InputStream to load data from it. */
URL aURL = new URL("ur Image URL");
URLConnection conn = aURL.openConnection();
conn.connect();
InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
/* Buffered is always good for a performance plus. */
BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
/* Decode url-data to a bitmap. */
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bis);
bis.close();
is.close();
/* Apply the Bitmap to the ImageView that will be returned. */
i.setImageBitmap(bm);
} catch (IOException e) {
 i.setImageResource(R.drawable.error); // Error image here
Log.e("DEBUGTAG", "Remote Image Exception", e);
}
```

Comment: and if the download fails? cause no connection or something?

Comment: look at the catch block.. there is IO exception to handle network failure

Comment: you dont have a separate class for this, cause this would be better for me?

Comment: class? or a method? u can make a method out of this wherein u pass the URl as a parameter... the core code remains the same...u might have to make return type bitmap of that method...